# Count all possible computer programs of length N

Tags: math, programming-languages, combinatorics

I will make this easy to understand using Javascript as language

Using ascii as alphabet, and given all possible "statements" of length N formed using ascii, how many will be a valid JS program. Example for length 8

```
var i=0; //Is a string 8 characters long, and valid JS
jar i=0; //Is a string 8 characters long, but invalid JS
gfjsjhh3 //Is a string 8 characters long, but invalid JS
now imagine we have all possible strings 8 characters long. 
How many will be valid JS?
```

Further rules:

1) variables are as short *as possible*

2) no blank spaces except where necessary

More formal definition of problem:

If we are given a grammar G for alphabet K, and also the collection of all possible combinations (statements) of length N that can be formed with K(or K* up to length N), how many of those statements will satisfy grammar G.

I know you are thinking this is some academic, away from reality stuff. However, if the number of statements that are programs is much less than the total number of combinations, you could use small "numbers" to refer to locations where these sparse programs appear in the sea of combinations, and be able to send this "address" instead of the whole program, greatly reducing payload

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. Are you saying that variables made of 2 characters are not allowed? Would different comment contents make the code different? Also, what work have you done on the problem so far and just where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you really expect an answer with a closed formula such as "number of programs of length N is N^3 + 52^(N/2) + ..."?

Comment: The grammar is usually only one aspect of validity checks. And very poor to capture your "as short as possible" requirement. I guess you might start by thinking about [derivation trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) based on some [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) grammar for JS. If you encode each node of the tree, you have something like the compression effect you describe. It will still allow invalid programs, and programs with long variable names, but as a starting point for proof of concept (whatever you concept may be) it should suffice.

Comment: Just so it's not misunderstood, JavaScript doesn't use ASCII.

Comment: @TomBlodget looking at the ascii table, I see all symbols that compose a valid JS program(=, [, (, +, -, etc)

Comment: @Henrik I am sure a closed form is pretty much impossible to obtain. However, I wonder if that would be easier to obtain if the language, or grammar, had some particular properties

Comment: @MvG I am thinking more of an upper limit. For programs length 1000, it could probably take the age of the universe to compute. Knowing that the # of valid programs pales in comparison with all combinations is a perfect starting point.

Comment: This is a valid JavaScript statement of 8 characters: ψ=ğ("")

Comment: @TomBlodget I am referring to the 8 bit classic ascii table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Right, JavaScript doesn't use ASCII.

Comment: @TomBlodget I said "Using ascii as alphabet" because UTF-8 has ascii as subset and one could write perfectly good JS code using only those 127 characters(or much less), and not indulge in using 2-4 bytes to represent one character(variable, fun name), when 1 byte is enough per character. Sure, you can now use exotic characters in your JS, but there is no free lunch and it will still add to the size of the program. This is an unnecessary point anyway; anybody with common sense will see beyond the language used as example and focus in the abstract matter

Comment: Abstractly, languages deal with literal values. A system that processes all valid programs in a language must deal all possible literal values. While identifiers, in general, don't affect the behavior of a program ([minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) could reduce your set of all possible programs), data like "" does matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar is usually only one aspect of validity checks, check out ES6 [§5.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantic-rules). And grammars are very poor to capture your “as short as possible” requirement. But grammars are a good tool to reason about things, so let's concentrate on that. It will still allow invalid programs, and programs with long variable names, but as a starting point for proof of concept (whatever you concept may be) it should suffice.

You might start by thinking about [derivation trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) based on some [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) grammar for JS. Something like sections §11 to §15 of the ES6 standard, but make sure that the grammar you use is going down to the character level, not treating a whole identifier as a single terminal. For your hypothetical compression scheem, if you encode the choice at each node of the tree, you have something like the compression effect you describe.

In order to count the number of programs of a given length, you could do [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) on the BNF rules. So if you have a rule which says

```
IndexedMemberExpression ::= MemberExpression '[' Expression ']'
```

(loosely modeled after ES6 [§12.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-hand-side-expressions)) then you know that an `IndexedMemberExpression` of length *n* is made up of a `MemberExpression` of length *i* and an `Expression` of length *n* − *i* − 2, for some 0 ≤ *i* ≤ *n* − 2, so if you know how many ways there are for those, you know for the whole expression. Have one array of length 1000 for each BNF non-terminal, fill them in order of increasing length, and you get the number of derivation trees (i.e. grammatically correct programs) for the root rule.

Actually an IndexedMemberExpression is just one kind of MemberExpression, and you'd want to sum all of those up. So it's more like this:

```py
allocate an arry of size 1000 for each non-terminal,
  and initialize all the elements to zero

for n from 0 to 1000:

  …

  # compute PrimaryExpression[n] first

  # rule MemberExpression ::= PrimaryExpression
  MemberExpression[n] = PrimaryExpression[n]

  # rule MemberExpression ::= MemberExpression '[' Expression ']'
  if n >= 2:
    for i from 0 to n - 2:
      MemberExpression[n] += MemberExpression[i] * Expression[n-i-2]

  # rule MemberExpression ::= MemberExpression '.' IdentifierName
  if n >= 1:
    for i from 0 to n - 1:
      MemberExpression[n] += MemberExpression[i] * IdentifierName[n-i-1]

  …
```

Do this for all the rules, in an order which makes sure that you fully update each non-terminal on the left hand side of the increments before using it for the first time on the right hand side.

Note that for almost any character sequence of length *n*, the corresponding string literal will be a valid JS expression of length *n* + 2. So don't expect the number of valid programs to have a radically different asymptotic behavior compared to the number of arbitrary character sequences.